# C#: Convert string from array to double wih dot separator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, double, separator

I am developing an Xamarin Android app in Visual Studio.

I have a string array of GPS coordinates like this:

```
*string[] DeviceLocations = { "23.2342;32.4544", "7.4321;9.5431", "12.4223;-23.3434" };*
```

In order to be able to pass them to my Google Map like Markers, they have to be converted to double values - with the "." as separator.

I have tried several different ways to do this, including:

1)

```
Double lat = Convert.ToDouble(splitPos[0].ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

2)

```
NumberFormatInfo info = new NumberFormatInfo();
info.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
info.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Double lat = Double.Parse(splitPos[0].ToString(), info);
```

3)

```
Double lat = XmlConvert.ToDouble(splitPos[0].ToString());
```

4)

```
Double lat = double.Parse(splitPos[1].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But all of them returns the "lat" with a "," instead of a ".".

Anyone got any other ideas of what I can try??? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: How are you getting `splitPos`?

Comment: I'm getting splitPos in a for loop like this: _string[] splitPos = DeviceLocations[i].Split(';');_

Comment: Problem is not in parsing the number I believe. The problem is when outputing the number. That is there you need to specify the format. Use `CultureInfo` or `NumberFormatInfo`.

Comment: @SorenA *they have to be converted to decimal values - with the "." as separator* - There is no such thing. A `decimal` is just a number. The separator is part of the culture-dependent formatting, so either you want a `decimal`, or you want a `string` that contains a decimal number in US format.

Comment: @Sani Singh Huttunen: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Where exactly  do you mean I should specify the format?

Comment: @SorenA Look at my answer. It's in the last line.

Comment: @Thorsten: Sorry My bad, I mean that they should be converted to a double - I have updated my question.

Comment: @SorenA Doesn't matter. The same is true for floats, doubles and decimals. As all of these are numeric types. You are mixing up numbers and their string representation. Only a string can contain a decimal separator. A number, by itself, does not. There is no way of telling a `decimal` or a `double` what decimal separator it has. You can only say which decimal separator should be used when converting a fractional number **to string**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One correct way would be this:

```
private static readonly CultureInfo USCULTURE = new CultureInfo("en-US");

// Go over all items
foreach (string latlon in DeviceLocations)
{
    // Get the split result
    string[] coordinates = latlon.Split(';');

    // Lat is first item of split array, Lon is second item
    double lat = Convert.ToDouble(coordinates[0], USCULTURE);
    double lon = Convert.ToDouble(coordinates[0], USCULTURE);

    // Now do something with the double values
    ...
}
```

I don't know what you mean by *all of them returns the "lat" with a "," instead of a "."*, but a double is just a double. Only when you **output** it, there's a decimal separator. So maybe the system where you output the number has `,` as decimal separator?

In that case you need to force the output to use US formatting:

```
string outputtableLat = lat.ToString("G", USCULTURE);
string outputtableLon = lon.ToString("G", USCULTURE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following would do:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<double,double>> ParseCoordinates(this IEnumerable<string> points, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
{
    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        var coordinates = point.Split(';');
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;

        if (!double.TryParse(coordinates[0], NumberStyles.Number, formatProvider, out x))
        {
            x = double.NaN;
        }

        if (!double.TryParse(coordinates[1], NumberStyles.Number, formatProvider, out y))
        {
            y = double.NaN;
        }

        yield return new Tuple<double, double>(x, y);
    }
}
```

I took the liberty of returning `double.NaN` in case of failed parses. Not sure if this is valid in your scenario, change accordingly but make sure you *do* have a way of recovering from malformed data.

And you'd use it like this:

```
string[] deviceLocations = { "23.2342;32.4544", "7.4321;9.5431", "12.4223;-23.3434" };
var coordinates = deviceLocations.ParseCoordinates(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Now you have your coordinates parsed. If you want to output them in any specific culture, simply leverage the `IFormattable` interface:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, coordinates.Select(c => $"Lat: {c.Item1.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}; Long: {c.Item2.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}")));
```